# Getting an error on new event Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

I am getting the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

and this is showing on line 1 of my page.

I am using the following code:

```
$('.hollaBackClick').live('click', function(){

    var currentElement = $(this);
    var hollaID = currentElement.attr('hollaID');
    var userID = currentElement.attr('userID');
    var username = currentElement.attr('username');

    var hollaBackBoxHTML = '<form id="hollaBackForm">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="hollaID" value="' + hollaID + '" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="' + userID + '" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="' + username + '" />' +
        '<textarea name="hollaBackContent" id="hollaBackContent" placeholder="HollardBack@' + username + '" />' +
        '<input type="submit" name="hollaBackSubmit" id="hollaBackSubmit" value="HollaBack" />' +
    '</form>';

    currentElement.after(hollaBackBoxHTML);

});
```

I am using click events all over the website and this is the only place I get the error and I am somewhat stumped into what could be causing the issue...

Comment: I should also mention removing all the code from within the click and even turning into a normal jquery click event still causes this error...

Comment: My guess is that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and there's nothing wrong with it. please provide more context information or even the complete file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code JSLint validates it, [click JSLint button here](http://jsfiddle.net/pYRwx/) - the problem could be with the values you are getting from the DOM elements

Comment: @ManseUK Hi there, the values are all fine, especially since if you see my question the error still occurs in using the even handler with nothing inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentElement.after(hollaBackBoxHTML);
```

are you trying to do like this?

Comment: That's not the issue, just removed it by accident, see the error code.

Comment: Nope, don't think so, I am going to double check the html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, I got confused and had two html elements with the same class one without the attributes. Changing the class solved the problem. So to confirm anyone else that has this issue make sure that your event is targeting the particular element you intend it for.

Thanks for you help guys!